# Нарушает ли бизнес логика, подмешанная во front-end приложение принципы разделения front/back-end?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Интерфейс блога развернут на Nuxt.js с использованием SSR (Server side render).

Проблема. **Нужно где-то хранить записи** (посты) **и считать статистику** просмотров определенного поста и лайки. Следовательно нужно использовать БД (например NeDB)

Есть несколько решений:

1. Хранить посты в виде .md файлов в репозитории GitHub, в этом случае,
   можно сгенерировать статику и не развертывать сервер. Статистику
   хранить как метаданные, но придется каждый раз при просмотре
   обовлять репозиторий, а делать этого ради инкремента счетчика не
   очень хочется.
2. Развернуть полноценный сервер для фронта и отдельный для API.
3. Интегрировать и развернуть фронт сервер и подмешать в него бизнес
   логику CRUD (create, delete. etc.). Но это может нарушать принципы
   разделения фронта и бэка.
4. Сгенерировать статику, использовать в качестве БД NeDB, но мне пока
   неизвестно как NeDB ведет себя в браузере, не хочется каждому
   клиенту грузить всю бд

Если использовать бизнес логику в Nuxt приложение, это нарушит принципы разделения front/backend?

Comment: Статистику вы легко можете возложить на соответствующий сервис от яндекса или гугла

Comment: etki - Надо считать стату определенного поста с свыводом цифры и так же его лайки!

Comment: А у вас планируется делать более одного фронт-энда, т.е. например отдельный мобильный сайт или мобильное приложение или еще что нибудь ?

Comment: @mike нет, только один фронт

Comment: Разделение на back и front придумано что бы можно было менять фронт не трогая бизнес логику и что бы было просто прикрутить вообще другой фронт. но в простых ситуациях все это излишне. не вижу ничего плохого если у вас вообще не будет никакого бака, а все запросы в БД будут прямо во фронте (в серверной части конечно). В конце концов 95% всех проектов так и живут, без всяких лишних прослоек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено. Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)

> Разделение на back и front придумано что бы можно было менять фронт не
>   трогая бизнес логику и что бы было просто прикрутить вообще другой
>   фронт. но в простых ситуациях все это излишне. не вижу ничего плохого
>   если у вас вообще не будет никакого бака, а все запросы в БД будут
>   прямо во фронте (в серверной части конечно). В конце концов 95% всех
>   проектов так и живут, без всяких лишних прослоек - [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)